# OpenMP - Nested parallel for loops within sections

Tags: c++, openmp

I have a time integration for loop, within which (to find the values of the arrays at the next time step) I am computing three equations essentially and each of the three equations are independent of one another and are roughly as computationally expensive as each other to approximate. Each equation is fundamentally a for loop calculation.

I would like to speed up the calculations as much as possible using openMP.

The first way I went about parallising this using openMP was just by parallising the for loops of each equation but still going through each equation 1 by 1, such as:

```
void derx(u, dudx, nthreads) {

   // X Derivative of u
   omp_set_num_threads(nthreads);
   #pragma parallel for
   {
     for (int i=0; i<Nx; i++) {
        dudx = ....
     }
   }
}

void dery(u, dudy, nthreads) {

   // Y Derivative of u
   omp_set_num_threads(nthreads);
   #pragma parallel for
   {
     for (int i=0; i<Nx; i++) {
        dudy = ....
     }
   }
}

void equation1(f1, f2, f3, output, nthreads) {
   
   // X Derivative of f1
   derx(f1, df1dx, nthreads); // parallel for loop inside

   // Y Derivative of f2
   dery(f2, df2dy, nthreads); // parallel for loop inside

   // Get output
   output = RHS1(f1,f2,f3,df1dx,df2dy);
}

void equation2(f1, f2, f3, output, nthreads) {
   
   // X Derivative of f1
   derx(f1, df1dx, nthreads); // parallel for loop inside

   // Y Derivative of f2
   dery(f2, df2dy, nthreads); // parallel for loop inside

   // Get output
   output = RHS2(f1,f2,f3,df1dx,df2dy);
}

void equation3(f1, f2, f3, output, nthreads) {
   
   // X Derivative of f1
   derx(f1, df1dx, nthreads); // parallel for loop inside

   // Y Derivative of f2
   dery(f2, df2dy, nthreads); // parallel for loop inside

   // Get output
   output = RHS3(f1,f2,f3,df1dx,df2dy);
}

int main
{
   for (int t=0; t<Nt; t++) {

      // STAGE 1 ---------------------------------------------
      equation1(f1,f2,f3,f1_temp,nthreads_total)
      equation2(f1,f2,f3,f2_temp,nthreads_total)
      equation3(f1,f2,f3,f3_temp,nthreads_total)


      // STAGE 2 ---------------------------------------------
      equation1(f1_temp,f2_temp,f3_temp,f1_final,nthreads_total)
      equation2(f1_temp,f2_temp,f3_temp,f2_final,nthreads_total)
      equation3(f1_temp,f2_temp,f3_temp,f3_final,nthreads_total)

      // STAGE 3 ---------------------------------------------
      // Calculate next time step variables
      f1, f2, f3 = function_final(f1_final, f2_final, f3_final);
   }
}
```

This did provide some performance boost, if OMP_NUM_THREADS was set to 9, each equation would be calculated using 9 threads, and worked as I expected it would. But I saw that if I increased the threads past 10, computation time would increase, probably due to the tasks involved in function1 not requiring so many threads. So to try fix this I wanted to do something where I split the total number of threads into 3 and computed equation 1, 2 and 3 concurrently with each equation using a third of the total number of threads.

So for example, if OMP_NUM_THREADS = 15, then 5 threads would be used to run functionA and function B to get equation 1, 5 threads to get equation 2, and like-wise for equation 3. I thought the best way to do this would be as follows:

```
void derx(u, dudx, nthreads) {

   // X Derivative of u
   omp_set_num_threads(nthreads);
   #pragma parallel for
   {
     for (int i=0; i<Nx; i++) {
        dudx = ....
     }
   }
}

void dery(u, dudy, nthreads) {

   // Y Derivative of u
   omp_set_num_threads(nthreads);
   #pragma parallel for
   {
     for (int i=0; i<Nx; i++) {
        dudy = ....
     }
   }
}

void equation1(f1, f2, f3, output, nthreads) {
   
   // X Derivative of f1
   derx(f1, df1dx, nthreads); // parallel for loop inside

   // Y Derivative of f2
   dery(f2, df2dy, nthreads); // parallel for loop inside

   // Get output
   output = RHS1(f1,f2,f3,df1dx,df2dy);
}

void equation2(f1, f2, f3, output, nthreads) {
   
   // X Derivative of f1
   derx(f1, df1dx, nthreads); // parallel for loop inside

   // Y Derivative of f2
   dery(f2, df2dy, nthreads); // parallel for loop inside

   // Get output
   output = RHS2(f1,f2,f3,df1dx,df2dy);
}

void equation3(f1, f2, f3, output, nthreads) {
   
   // X Derivative of f1
   derx(f1, df1dx, nthreads); // parallel for loop inside

   // Y Derivative of f2
   dery(f2, df2dy, nthreads); // parallel for loop inside

   // Get output
   output = RHS3(f1,f2,f3,df1dx,df2dy);
}

int main
{
   omp_set_nested(1);
   for (int t=0; t<Nt; t++) {

      // STAGE 1 ---------------------------------------------
      #pragma omp sections num_threads(3)
      {
         #pragma omp section
         {
            equation1(f1,f2,f3,f1_temp,nthreads_total/3)
         }

         #pragma omp section
         {
            equation2(f1,f2,f3,f2_temp,nthreads_total/3)
         }

         #pragma omp section
         {
            equation3(f1,f2,f3,f3_temp,nthreads_total/3)
         }
      }


      // STAGE 2 ---------------------------------------------
      #pragma omp sections num_threads(3)
      {
         #pragma omp section
         {
            equation1(f1_temp,f2_temp,f3_temp,f1_final,nthreads_total/3)
         }

         #pragma omp section
         {
            equation2(f1_temp,f2_temp,f3_temp,f2_final,nthreads_total/3)
         }

         #pragma omp section
         {
            equation3(f1_temp,f2_temp,f3_temp,f3_final,nthreads_total/3)
         }
      }

      // STAGE 3 ---------------------------------------------
      // Calculate next time step variables
      f1, f2, f3 = function_final(f1_final, f2_final, f3_final);
   }
}
```

And the numerical results were correct and the same as before, but many more threads than I wanted were being created, for example this is the result when I ran my first suggested code with OMP_NUM_THREADS=6:

[first method thread count](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ykAJ0.png)

[first method timeline](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4xBZL.png)

And this was the performance profiler's results when I ran the second method with OMP_NUM_THREADS=6:

[second method thread count](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QJZqN.png)

[second method timeline](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3C2wU.png)

I know it probably not a big deal, but if it possible to make the second method only create 6 threads like the first method does, whilst still maintaining the performance increase, that would be ideal.

Thanks

P.S. Also I realise there will be some things I wil nead to change if the total number of threads is not divisible by 3 exactly, but I will tackle that problem later

Comment: How large is `Nx`?

Comment: Well I can change it, if Nx is small (~100) then the performance doesnt increase much with more threads, but if Nx is larger (~1000), then more threads does help. With method  1 I mean. But most of the time Nx will be around 300 or so, so thats why method 2 will be better in most cases if it does eventually work, since then its using fewer threads per equation but the same number of total threads, since there are 3 equations being solved cocurrently

Comment: 100 should be large enough for good distribution. I still don't get why you constantly fork and join the threads by opening new parallel sections. You just create a ton of synchronization overhead. Why can't you put at least the `dudx` and `dvdx` computations into the same loop?

Comment: Also, are these `Nx` completely independent equation systems or are there dependencies between them?

Comment: within each division into three sections, there should not be any dependencies, to my undersatnding at least

between batched of 3 sections, i.e. the "stages", there are dependencies

Comment: but I think you're right that I dont need to keep forking, I can probably just aply a barrier after each batch of 3 sections, since stage 2 depends on all 3 of the sections in stage 1

Comment: Why don't you use tasks to solve your problem?

Answer (score 0):

This is a bit of a shot in the dark, but try this:

```cpp
#  pragma omp parallel
   {
#      pragma omp for nowait
       for (int i=0; i<Nx; i++) {
           f1_temp = function1(f1);
       }
#      pragma omp for nowait
       for (int i=0; i<Nx; i++) {
           f2_temp = function1(f2);
       }
#      pragma omp for nowait
       for (int i=0; i<Nx; i++) {
           f3_temp = function1(f3);
       }
   }
```

So there is only one parallel section, meaning threads stay active in between loops. Inside, there are `omp for` (not `omp parallel for`!) sections that are marked as `nowait`. That means idle threads can continue forward and should be able to start processing the next part. There is an implicit barrier at the end of the parallel section, so at that point everything is synchronized.

**This only works if the loops are independent or only elements with the same `i` index are dependent on each other.**

Some notes:

1. I assume you did simplify the code so much that we cannot see how the use of `f1_temp` and so forth is thread-safe
2. I also assume there is a good reason why you don't simply write

```
#   pragma omp parallel for
    for(int i = 0; i < Nx; ++i) {
        f1_temp = function1(f1);
        f2_temp = function1(f2);
        f3_temp = function1(f3);
    }
```

3. You might want to keep the parallel section open even longer, outside the `Nt` loop and use a barrier + `pragma omp single` for the final part of the computation

Another pattern that may apply:

```cpp
input_type* fs[] = { &f1, &f2, &f3 };
output_type* f_temps[] = { &f1_temp, &f2_temp, &f3_temp };

#pragma omp parallel for collapse(2)
for(int i = 0; i < Nx; ++i)
    for(int j = 0; j < 3; ++j)
        *f_temps[j] = function1(*fs[j]);
```

Comment: Hi

Thanks for replying, sorry for not including more info. I have edited my initial question to add more info. It is a runge kutta time integration method, but I've only included two steps since the other steps are basically the same.

And the equations use 3 states.

Hopefully this clears things up